# parametric representation for a point in the line or the line

Tags: linear-algebra

Say there are 4 bounds $x_{min}$ and $x_{max}$ and $y_{min}$ and $y_{max}$. My book says one way to formulate an equation for a straight line segment is to use the parametric representation where the coordinate positions represent the two coordinate positions $(x_0, y_0)$ and $(x_{end}, y_{end})$ :
$$x=x_0+u(x_{end}-x_0)$$
$$y=y_0+u(y_{end}-y_0)$$
And we can know if a straight line joining these points intersect with the above given bounds, by assigning a value of the bounds to $x$ or $y$ as needed and solving for $u$, if $u$ is between $0$ and $1$ then the line intersects else it does not.

My question is where did this parametric representation for a line even come  from? I know it's  not from a vector representation since it's not coordinate position's  parametric representation and why even involve: $x_{end}-x_0$ when we could know by simple subtraction if the bounds are met with?

Comment: I understand that you want to know how you arrive at these equation, but I don't understand your second question. Do you want to know what the boundaries of $u$ are under the assumption that $x_{min} \leq x \leq x_{max}$ and $y_{min}\leq y \leq y_{max}$?

Comment: @Ernie060 , I meant if $x_0$ <$x_{min}$ then x lies outside the bound, and if not it lies on or within the bound, so, why even involve the calculation of $x_{end}-x_0$  when this is not necessary to know if the bounds have been met?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A somewhat non-rigorous derivation of your equations could go something like this. Let $P_0(x_0, y_0)$ and $P_{end}(x_{end}, y_{end})$ be the end points of the line segment. Let $\vec{r}_0$ and $\vec{r}_{end}$, respectively, be their position vectors with respect to the origin $O$.  Suppose that $\vec{r}\,$ is the position vector with respect to $O$ of an arbitrary point $P(x,y)$ of the line segment. The geometry is illustrated below:

[image]

Then the distance from $P_0$ to $P$ must be $\geq 0$, but less than or equal to that from $P_0$ to $P_{end}$, that is, $$0 \leq \lVert\vec{r}-\vec{r}_0 \rVert \leq \lVert\vec{r}_{end} - \vec{r}_0 \rVert. \tag{1}$$ However, the displacement vector $(\vec{r}-\vec{r}_0)$ of $P$ with respect to $P_0$, and $(\vec{r}_{end} - \vec{r}_0)$ of $P_{end}$ with respect to $P_0$, are *parallel*, so there is some scalar $u$ for which $$\begin{align}\vec{r}-\vec{r}_0 = u\,(\vec{r}_{end} - \vec{r}_0). \tag{2}\end{align}$$ Substituting from equation (1) into (2) yields $0 \leq u\,\left(\lVert\vec{r}_{end}-\vec{r}_0 \rVert\right) \leq \lVert\vec{r}_{end} - \vec{r}_0 \rVert$, from which it follows that $$\begin{align}0 \leq u \leq 1. \tag{3}\end{align}$$ The *component equations* of vector equation (2) are your two equations (answering your first question), but these equations are *restricted* to values of $x$ and $y$ for which condition (3) is true. Conversely, a possible pair $(x,y)$ of coordinate values, say $(x_{min}, y_{min})$ or $(x_{max}, y_{max})$, define a point on the *line segment* only if they satisfy your two equations for a *single* value of $u$ in the interval (3). So, as your book suggests, by inserting these values for $x$ and $y$, then computing $$u = \dfrac{x-x_0}{x_{end}-x_0} = \dfrac{y-y_0}{y_{end}-y_0},\tag{4}$$ you can conclude that the point is on the line segment (or, for example, the *lines* $x=x_{min}$ and $y = y_{min}$ *intersect* at the same point of the line segment) only if you obtain the same value of $u$ in both cases, and it is in the range (3).

With regard to your last question, you see that only values for $x$ in the range $x_0 \leq x \leq x_{end}$ could correspond to points on the line segment, so candidates for $x_{min}$ and $x_{max}$ would have to lie in this range. Similarly, candidates for $y_{min}$ and $y_{max}$ would have to lie in the range $y_0 \leq y \leq y_{end}$. However, to guarantee that any pair $(x,y)$ of coordinates chosen from these ranges of values actually lie on the line segment, the coordinates must be shown to satisfy equations (4), subject to condition (3).